# How to take irrational numbers and cases out of this inequality’s proof

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Consider the following simple inequality in rational numbers $x,r$ :

$$\text{If } x\geq 0,\ r\geq 0 \text{ and } r^2\geq 2,\ x^3-6x+4r\geq 0.\tag{1}$$

If one is allowed to use irrational numbers such as $\sqrt{2}$, the proof
of (1) is obvious : we simply write $x^3-6x+4r=4(r-\sqrt{2})+(x-\sqrt{2})^2(x+2\sqrt{2})$.

If one is allowed to distinguish cases, it is also not too hard to prove (1) :
indeed (1) is equivalent to $4r \geq 6x-x^3$ ; we may assume that the RHS is nonnegative,
so that $6\geq x^2$. We are then done by remarking that $(4r)^2-(6x-x^3)^2=(8-x^2)(x^2-2)^2$.

I am looking for an even better proof of (1), one that uses neither irrational
numbers nor case-making. This leads me to ask :

(1) Is there a polynomial $F\in{\mathbb Q}_+[U,V,W,Z_1,\ldots,Z_m]$ and polynomials $P_1,P_2,\ldots,P_m\in {\mathbb Q}[x,r]$ such that
the algebraic identity $x^3-6x+4r=F(x,r,r^2-2,P_1(x,r)^2,\ldots,P_m(x,r)^2)$ holds in ${\mathbb Q}[x,r]$ ?

(2) Is there a rational function $F\in{\mathbb Q}_+(U,V,W)$ and rational fractions $P_1,P_2,\ldots,P_m\in {\mathbb Q}(x,r)$such that
the algebraic identity $x^3-6x+4r=F(x,r,r^2-2,P_1(x,r)^2,\ldots,P_m(x,r)^2)$ holds in ${\mathbb Q}(x,r)$ ?

(3) If the answer to (1) and (2) is negative, is there a proof using only 
standard inequalities such as AM-GM, Cauchy-Schwarz, Holder, convexity etc but
not irrational numbers or case-making.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
$$x^3+2r+2r\ge 3\sqrt[3]{x^3\cdot 4r^2}\ge 6x$$

Comment: Thanks. This answer not only (3) but also (2), as $(x^3+4r)-6x=\frac{(x^3+4r)^3-(6x)^3}{(x^3+4r)^2+(x^3+4r)(6x)+(6x)^2}$. It seems however that your answer has no influence on (1)